# Default page is displayed before displaying redirected page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side app that redirects to another app for login & registration. So in `app.razor` I did:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin/>
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <p>Please wait...</p>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And the redirect component:

```
public class RedirectToLogin : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        //here navigateto....
    }
}
```

This partially works because I do get redirected, however, the default home page is initially displayed.

Is it possible to change this behavior so that the redirection occurs before the home page is loaded/shown?

Comment: I assume your default page you are referring to is using `MainLayout`. Changing it to different layout (to the one your login page is using) will solve this problem.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal The login page is in the separate app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to edit mainlayout.razor page and add your control RedirectToLogin there becuase Blazor has a defualt RedirectToLogin.razor control that will redirect also to the defualt Authentication.razor. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565364/blazor-hosted-authorize-immediately-before-displaying-application)